# Starting a batch file from another batch file only opens CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I start a batch file from another batch file, it just opens a new CMD window named just "TEST.bat", and doesn't run the actual batch. Running it manually works fine.

```
cd %~dp0\Colours\TEST.bat
start "TEST.bat"
```

I have tried many different ways to run the batch, but it all does the same thing. I've also tried to run the batch as administrator but same result again.

Full code(not finished): http://pastebin.com/GE8yJP0J

Comment: If you look at `start /?` you will see that you can specify a title for the new window by enclosing it in double-quotes.  This means that if your command is wrapped in double-quotes, it is treated as the title and the command-window opens with no command to execute.  You need `start "" "TEST.bat"`.

Comment: This doesnt work either. It comes up with an error saying it cannot find 'TEST.bat'

Comment: Replace `cd` by `cd /D`...

Comment: Nope. With the code from TripeHound it comes up with the same error

Comment: Use full paths. Don't use start but use call if you want control to return. See `Start /?` and `call /?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run another batch file, use `call` not `start`. Also: `cd` expects a directory, not a filename.

```
cd "%~dp0\Colours"
call TEST.bat
```

Comment: Thanks.
I tried that, and this time it doesn't do anything at all.

The code i gave you was only a part of my batch file, so i tried making a new batch file with only that code and it worked.

Why wont this work with everything else I've got in my original batch file? I'm new to batches so I've mostly copy pasted and edited stuff I found online.

Comment: @MrVib3r: without seeing the **complete** code this is impossible to answer

Comment: @MrVib3r, edit your question and put the full code in the question.